# How to use a double while loop in python?

Tags: python

Does a python double while loop work differently than a java double loop?
When I run this code:

```
i = 0
j = 1
while i < 10:
    while j < 11:
        print i, j
        j+=1
    i+=1
```

I get the following output:

0 1 
0 2 
0 3 
0 4 
0 5 
0 6 
0 7 
0 8 
0 9 
0 10

I want it to keep looping to print 1 0, 1 1, 1 2, ... 2 0, 2 1, 2 3... etc. Why does it stop after only one iteration?

Comment: You need to reset  `j` before every time you start executing the inner loop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because your j gets 11 after first iteration. Need to reset it:

```
i = 0
j = 1
while i < 10:
    j= 1 #<-- here
    while j < 11:
        print i, j
        j+=1
    i+=1
```

Answer (score 6):

You probably want to move the `j` "initialization" inside the first loop.

```
i = 0
while i < 10:
    j = 1
    while j < 11:
        print i, j
        j+=1
    i+=1
```

In your code, as soon as `j` gets to `11`, then the inner loop stops executing (with the `print` statement).  In my code, I reset `j` each time `i` changes so the inner loop will execute again.

Answer (score 1):

Alternative:

```
list1=list(range(0,10))
list2=list(range(0,11))
l = [(x,y) for x in list1 for y in list2]
for a in l:
    for b in a:
        print b,
    print ""
```

Explanation:

**Step 1**:
Storing 2 lists `list1=list(range(0,10))` and `list2=list(range(0,11))` so that we know what values to expect in left and right values.

**Step 2**:
Getting a list of all combinations of the list of pairs generated by taking values from list1 and list2 and storign it in l using the command `l = [(x,y) for x in list1 for y in list2]`

**Step 3**:
Get each element of the list `l`. Since we want a pair to be printed in the same line use `print b,`

**Step 4**:
To print next line (`\n`) character between each successive element, use the `print ""` command that is shown in the last line.

Comment: If you could please edit your answer and explain what the code you're showing does, and why/how that code answers the question, it could really help.

Comment: @Lea Cohen, i have added the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

A more pythonic approach:

```
for i in range( 10 ):
    for j in range( 1, 11 ):
        print i, j
```